# CBMC call from Python?

Tags: python, cbmc

Is there a way that I can call CBMC from Python or is there any wrapper or API for it available?

My Problem is the following. I want to create a C function automatically in Python (this works quite well) and sent them to CBMC from Python for checking and get feedback if the function is OK or not.

Answer (score 2):

Since CBMC can produce a significant amount of output your best bet would be to work out how to call if from the command line.

Once you have done that then you can use the `subprocess.call` [library function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Call) to call the same with the output redirected to a file, then process the contents of the file.

I would suggest using the `--xml-ui` flag to tell CBMC that you would like machine processable output.

Answer (score 0):

CBMC can also produce JSON output using `--json-ui` since version 5.5, which is more compact than the XML output. Also note that you can suppress certain messages by adjusting the verbosity level using `--verbosity <some number between 0 and 10>`.